# I deployed a website to heroku and changed some of my app.js file. Why can't my templates be accessed on the local server anymore?

Tags: javascript, html, css

None of my templates are loading on the local server and I need someone to look at the app.js code to see if there is something missing or extra information I could delete. My index.html points to  
I deployed the website to heroku a long time ago and now I just want to run it in the browser - but can't work out what I might have added to deploy it. Sorry, I am a beginner so I hope someone might be patient.

```
angular.module('BandApp', ['ngRoute', 'angular-storage', 
'RouteControllers', 'UserService']);

angular.module('BandApp').config(function($routeProvider, 
$locationProvider) {

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeController'
})
              .when('/listen', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/listen.html'
});
});
```

Comment: Try adding details such as what error messages you may be seeing

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] 
    at angular.js:38
    at angular.js:4779
    at q (angular.js:357)
    at g (angular.js:4740)
    at db (angular.js:4662)
    at c (angular.js:1842)
    at Mc (angular.js:1863)
    at qe (angular.js:1748)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (angular.js:33129)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: Looks like Angular, what version? How are you building? What's the `baseHref` in the `angular.json` set to? This is a tough one to trouble shoot just going by the info provided.

Comment: Yes, it was on the offchance that might be the wrong part. I'm coming back to this after a long time so I'm struggling to remember how to set up. Basehref is set to /

Comment: Start in browser dev tools network and see what is or isn't loading and paths for files not loading